# Ошибка при подключении к PDO: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Салют народ, крч у меня не хочет подключаться...

**mysql.php**

```
<?
class Mysql {

    private $db;
    private $config;

    public function __construct(){

    $this->config = include __DIR__ .'/config.php';
    $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->config['dbname']};host={$this->config['dbhost']}, {$this->config['dbuser']}, {$this->config['dbpassword']}");
    }

    function query($sql, $params=[])
    {
        $sth - $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sth = $sth->execute($params);
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }

}
```

Вот такую ошибку выводит когда создаю класс:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. in E:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\blackmarket\core\mysql.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: in
>   E:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\blackmarket\core\mysql.php on line 9

Comment: Приведите значение dbhost

Comment: Попробуйте еще исправить проблему с кодировкой в логах, чтобы увидеть скрытую часть сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, проголосуйте за него и отметьте верным, нажав на галочку слева от вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь стоит проверить, доступен ли хост, указанный в настройках, для подключения. Проверьте его доступность с помощью команд `ping` и `nslookup`. Если в качестве хоста указано домменое имя, попробуйте указать вместо него IP-адрес.

---

На основе ответа к вопросу:
[PHP error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: (while getting information from other site.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6275627/2486051)

---

**ОБНОВЛЕНО**

[PDO::__construct](http://php.net/pdo.construct)

У вас ошибка в этой строке (в параметре `$dsn` ошибка):

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->config['dbname']};host={$this->config['dbhost']}, {$this->config['dbuser']}, {$this->config['dbpassword']}");
```

Правильно вот так:

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$this->config['dbname']};host={$this->config['dbhost']}", $this->config['dbuser'], $this->config['dbpassword']);
```

Comment: Надо было мне конфиг тоже прикрепить:
  <?
 return array(
 'dbhost' => 'localhost',
 'dbname' => 'blackshop',
 'dbuser' => 'root',
 'dbpassword' => ''
 );

Comment: Я не думаю что стоит пингом проверять localhost. Это локалхост ну...

Comment: @cr1gger, я ваш конфиг только сейчас увидел, предположение было для общего случая.

Comment: @cr1gger, я дополнил свой ответ

Comment: Спасибо, я понял свою ошибку.